# Cron job to run a PHP script every 90 seconds between 5AM and 10PM?

Tags: php, linux, cron

I am looking for a way to run a PHP script between two set times (probably 5AM and 10PM), every 90 seconds.  I was thinking of just making a bash script to move the file in/out of a directory at different times, but that would be messy and make all sorts of errors.  Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Does this have to be every 90 seconds?  Can you do every 60 or 120 instead?

Comment: 120 would be fine, i suppose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get a 90 seconds interval you could e.g. create two `crontab` entries with an interval of 3 minutes and delay one of them by 90 seconds:

```
-*/3 5-22 * * * your_script.php
-*/3 5-22 * * * sleep 90;your_script.php
```

Comment: That sounds like a really decent solution.  I will give it a shot tomorrow, thanks.  Wouldn't a bach script that essentially did the same thing allow me to do one cron entry?  `myscirpt.php sleep 90 myscript.php` along with a 3 minute cron entry?

Comment: @lorsungcu: Yes, that's basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if 90 seconds is possible, but here's 60

```
*/1 5,6,7,8,9,10 * * * root php your_script.php
```

And here's 120

```
*/2 5,6,7,8,9,10 * * * root php your_script.php
```

If you really really really need every 90 seconds, have cron run it every minute, put your entire php script in a "while ( $n < 2 )" loop, and sleep for 30 sec at the end of the loop.

Better yet, to keep your code and it's schedule apart, write a bash or PHP wrapper to call/include your script once, then again in 30 sec. Cron would call the wrapper every minute.

Answer (score 0):

As from this [link](http://quartz.10975.n7.nabble.com/cron-expression-starting-every-90-seconds-1-1-2-minutes-td2005.html) and modifying it for the time range

> One as: "0 0/3 5-22 * * ?" to fire every third min
>   The second as: "30 1/2 5-22 * * ?" This will take care of the 90 second